# How make popover be open on page load?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I use popover in my code like this:

```
var popOverSettings = {
        placement: 'top',
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        selector: '[rel="popover"]',
        content: function () {
            return 'hello world';
        }
    }

$('body').popover(popOverSettings).popover('show');

<div  rel='popover'>Show popover</div>
```

I expected to see the popover open but it's not working.

Comment: What is the HTML markup?

Comment: @Zim I updated with HTML markup

Comment: Where in the markup does the javascript execute? Before or after your div? Did you try it in a jquery `$( document ).ready(function() { console.log( "everything loaded" ); });`? Got any console errors?

Comment: I did all. There was no Error.
I found out should use an id or class instead of 'body'.

Answer (score 0):

$('body') should be change to an id or a class like this:

```
$('#example').popover(popOverSettings).popover('show');

<div id="exapmle" rel='popover'>Show popover</div>
```